# What are the differences between IE9’s IE8 emulation and honest-to-God IE8?

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9, ie8-compatibility-mode

I’m running into an issue where some icons aren’t showing up in IE8 on XP, but when I run IE9 on Win 7 with document & browser modes set to IE8, the issue doesn’t present itself.

So I’m wondering what the known differences are between IE8 emulation and the real deal. Let’s hear ’em!

Comment: IE8 was never honest to god, that's why it was cast down from browser heaven

Comment: Maybe the issue is outside the browser.. If you examin the requests with Fiddler or Charles, do you get any difference in the requests?

Comment: @Ben Not the case, see below and my linked test case!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. [`window.performance` exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5825385/javascript-can-i-detect-ie9-if-its-in-ie7-or-ie8-compatibility-mode?rq=1#comment6688213_5825510)
2. The UA includes the token “Trident/5.0” instead of “Trident/4.0”. [Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff986085(v=VS.85).aspx).
3. Per [Paul Irish](http://paulirish.com/2011/browser-market-pollution-iex-is-the-new-ie6/): “IE9’s IE8 mode: [intermittently](http://twatlr.com/thread/113376848716627968) false positives on a feature test for inline SVG. Renders CSS differently than true IE8, and is [crashier](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/issues/detail?id=334) than the real one.”
4. Real IE8 does not allow text to be `transparent`, but IE9’s emulation does. [JSFiddle demo and screenshots](http://jsfiddle.net/alanhogan/dM5at/).
5. In IE9’s IE8 mode, you can only style visited links differently by `color` (it’s a privacy fix that prevents checking if a URL is in your browser history).
6. <del>http://ajh.us/ie8-9</del>

Answer (score 5):

More differences:

1. CSS visited/link privacy fixes still apply to compatibility modes for obvious reasons.
2. No support for HTML+TIME because it is rarely used.

Answer (score 0):

IE8(at the very least, 64bit version on Windows 7) will randomly fail, and sometimes outright crashes, when JSON.stringify is used to serialize an object with nested arrays, ie:

```
var someModel = {
    "pages": [{
        "fields": [{}]
    }]
};
```

This doesn't happen in IE8 compat mode. This jsfiddle example is using knockout(it's an example from when I first came across it), but it can be tracked all the way to JSON.stringify http://jsfiddle.net/5LPSx/10/

Answer (score 0):

Certain javascript behavior is different. For instance, the [JScript DontEnum bug](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/ECMAScript_DontEnum_attribute#JScript_DontEnum_Bug) looks be fixed in IE10 emulation of IE8.