# $.browser.msie and IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I am trying to detect ALL versions of IE by using jquery `$.browser.msie`. 
It works for 8, 7, 6, but it ignores IE9. Why is that and what is a solution for javascript to detect ie9?

JS version: jQuery JavaScript Library **v1.5**

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537509%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using? v1.5.1 was the [first to support IE9](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2011/03/02/jquery-1-5-1-supports-ie9.aspx).

Comment: jQuery JavaScript Library v1.5

Comment: That's your problem... you need to upgrade jQuery to at least 1.5.1

Comment: that worked ;) write that as the answer, so I could accept it! thanks!

Answer (score 3):

As of version `1.9` of jQuery `$.browser` is no longer supported. Use `jQuery.suport` instead. With this change you'll need to check on what functionality you want to check. So just browser check is no longer supported in it. It is recommended to do a feature check instead of browser check.

[Docs here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.support/)

Answer (score 2):

IE9 can emulate older browsers, causing the variety of "works/doesn't work" responses you see here.

"Trident/5.0" is present in IE9's user-agent string in all modes, according to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5825385/javascript-can-i-detect-ie9-if-its-in-ie7-or-ie8-compatibility-mode).

Answer (score 1):

It works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/jcxXH/

Answer (score 0):

you can override the detection of IE noFullScreen: { msie: /msie [0-6]/, ... } to 
noFullScreen: { msie: /abcdefgh/ }