# jQuery error in Internet Explorer - Object doesn't support property or method 'addEventListener' occurred

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple HTML file with jQuery script calling a web service.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function makeRequest(url, messageString) {
        return $.ajax({
            url,
            headers: {
                'Authorization': 'Bearer XXXXX',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            method: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: messageString,
        });
    }
    function request1() {
        var messageString = '{"data":{"sample_data":"4.40%"}}';
        const url = 'https://url/v1/projects/path/results';
        return makeRequest(url, messageString);
    }
    $.when(request1())
        .then(function (data1) {
            $('#level1').html(data1[0].data.content);
        });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="level1"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Everything works fine in Chrome but when I try to open it in Internet Explorer 9 it fails. When I debug I found this error:

```
Unhandled exception at line 3, column 147 in 
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js
0x800a01b6 - Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support 
property or method 'addEventListener' occurred
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: @AlonEitan Perhaps I'm misunderstanding, but according to jQuery's [Browser Support](https://jquery.com/browser-support/), does this not say that the current version should work in IE 9+?

Comment: Oh, so I got confused with ie8 then, thanks for letting me know

Comment: Nothing in your code creates an event listener, I don't see why it would run into that error.

Comment: Open the console, and check, that you're really running the page in IE9 mode.

Comment: First thing I look at when I'm getting unexpected IE incompatibility issues is [Compatibility Mode](https://www.howtogeek.com/128289/how-to-disable-compatibility-mode-in-internet-explorer/). If necessary, you can read [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5825385/javascript-can-i-detect-ie9-if-its-in-ie7-or-ie8-compatibility-mode) for a bit more information.

Comment: Also, IE9 supports `addEventListener`, so something else is wrong

Comment: BTW - You have in your ajax this: `url,` which should be `url: url,` (I think)

Comment: @AlonEitan: That's new shorthand syntax that lets you elide a property name that matches the variable name that holds the value. `var url = "foo"; var obj = {url, bar: "baz"}; // {url: "foo", bar: "baz"}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your HTML document doesn't have a `doctype` declaration. This is needed for IE9 to include `addEventListener`. Without it, you're in quirks mode, and things will not behave as you'd expect.

Put this at the top of your HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```